# Typescript type an object key with data

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've got this code how to type dynamically data param of onHandlerData function?

```
export interface UserFormDto {
  credentials: UserCredentialsDto | null;
  details: UserDetailsDto | null;
  address: UserAddressDto | null;
}
const [data, setData] = useState<UserFormDto>({
  credentials: null,
  details: null,
  address: null,
});
const onHandlerData = (
  type: keyof UserFormDto,
  data: UserFormDto["credentials"]
) => {
  setData((data) => {
    return { ...data, [type]: data };
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's a problem with the implementation of `onHandlerData` (not just its types), you're shadowing the `data` parameter with the `data` parameter in the `setData` callback. You'll need a different name for that.

Once you have that, you can use a generic type parameter to handle ensuring `type` and `data` work together, like this:

```typescript
const onHandlerData = <KeyType extends keyof UserFormDto,>(
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    type: KeyType,
//        ^^^^^^^
    data: UserFormDto[KeyType]
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
) => {
    setData((current) => {
        return { ...current, [type]: data };
    });
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwK4GcCmBlGBDGaC+cAZlBCHAERRrYDGMFA3AFDMwCeYacAqulAGFqAEzQA7GMGwAbFABEYEOAF5EADwBccMUhAAjNFHwsOXXvzlocwWQqWqE7LTv2HjbTtz6GAgsOHUKPKKKogAXs66BkYsaGqQsHDAEoZEdF78AGLQIHaIzHCFcLQi4pIyKFregqUSUrYhAD7aSNLSLEVwotayVRZW2DbBSs06bR1F2P6Blea+02hBeaOt7czutBBiKPAA2sK42AA0cOgwcocAuqGomDh4ADzV2VC5igB8ABQIBUUlaKI6hVIm0jr9Ct1Br0WqDwXApgFFrMxtIwfgAJQsTbbeBbAAS2DEwmkhguOFCDwA0mh2AAVTxwOJ4IkoOAAaxpECIcygLzeECOXzhpjQWmpdM8YM6BxwfUMfLsu3F9K4l2Y6JU73ynTOZOwn0+tCQUGoEg1yi1P06nWoMGNYkQcAAdC6jSayiddiLLloZdg4O5OhiWO5RLRpNhqHASfAUGQ0NVLD1ZomBkM7Cx8YTiaTDp8KJChhQTnGQAn+snMXAAPTVuAAdWgbJQJwABn7W0lWf7U8m7Mws0SSVA9fmETNi6d472oSgq7W4ABRE3QeGs0QoYAiNsdrvwnlJ2f9oA)

*(The `,` after the generic type parameter definition is so that it works with JSX. It tells the parser that that `<...>` thing isn't an element definition.)*

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve it I could think of is to use generic, like this:

```js
const onHandlerData = <T extends keyof UserFormDTo>(
  type: T,
  data: UserFormDto[T]
) => {
  setData((oldData) => {
    return { ...oldData, [type]: data };
  });
};
```

Comment: Heh, we posted the same basic solution almost simultaneously. But you priobably want to fix the `data` shadowing issue as well. :-)